# Tool for txt log file analysis

Tags: python, text, rtf

I do a lot of reverse engineering from logs and am looking for a simple tool that'll do the following:

1. Take the plain text log file as input
2. Change the font color to the one I specify for texts I specify via yet another text file

For example, suppose the original log file is as follows:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4721)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleInstallPackage(ActivityThread.java:4661)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2467)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4721)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:110)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.run(ActivityThread.java:5414)
at android.os.Handler.handleMessage(Handler.java:1026)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:930)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

And I specify the following lines in file_1.txt:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2467)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
```

Then I'd want those two lines log.txt to be changed to a different color regardless of whereever they occur in the text, even if they are separated by other lines (in this case the other lines should retain their font color)

Also, I may specify a bunch of different "file_1"s and each of the pattern is expected to be colored in the original log file. Bonus if the tool detects any conflicts tht may arise but for now it's not mandatory. I was looking to write a quick script in python but it's turning out to be too complicated but any suggestions at this point help.

I tried developing a quick script using pyRTF3 and also looked into vi/vim

Comment: As a suggestion, does `grep` help you with what you want? In supported terminals it will return matching lines with the search text highlighted and you can get surrounding lines (context) and line numbers as output (among other options). For example: `grep -n -C 1 'handleBindApplication' file.log`

Comment: Thanks, I also once there is match I also want to change the font color of the match and save it as text (I know it can't be plain text anymore so probably rtf)